# How do I ban/kick multiple users in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was wondering is there any way to ban/kick multiple users from a server on discord using one command? It might be 2 members or even 10 members would there be any way to do this? And if someone does know the answer PLEASE help me out and I will be forever grateful to you kind stranger!

Comment: i don't think there a command right now that accept multiple as an input, for now an await for loop will work for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pointed out in the comments, you can't kick or ban multiple users with one command **natively** in discord.py . You can however always write your own functions, which deals with that.

---

```
async def kick_multiple(memberList):
    for member in memberList:
        await member.kick()

@bot.command()
async def kickCommand(ctx):
    membersToKick = [] # fill with wanted members
    await kick_multiple(membersToKick) # only one command
```

You can also move this command to a different file, if you don't want to have it in your main.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `commands.Greedy` on your `discord.Member` typecasted argument. As the name 'greedy' suggest, it takes all arguments of your specific typecast and converts them into a list of arguments

> English definition of greediness : intense and selfish desire for something. (Implying you want it all, leave nothing and plunder everything)

Then you can use a `for` loop to kick/ban them one-by-one

```
async def ban(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]=None, *, reason=None):
     if not members: 
         return await ctx.send('provide at least one member argument....')
     if not reason:
         reason = "my server my reasoning"
     for member in members: # members is a list that greedy has created
         try:
           await member.ban(reason=reason)
         except discord.Forbidden:
           pass
```

here is an example of how it will work:

**References**

- [commands.Greedy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy)

[image: Example usage]

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely try it out!